# move a Flash object forth and back along the X axis with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am creating a flash animation with a flash object that moves along the X axis back and forth. I would like to move the object for example from position x=10 to position x=100 then stay in position x=100 for 2 seconds and go back with the same motion characteristics to the initial position. I am using Tween Classes, that let me change eases and so on, i am also using the Tween yoyo method. The problem is that I don't know how to make the object stay for some seconds in the second position (before going back to the initial position) and I don't know how to stop the yoyo event. I want the object to go back and forth and then stay in the initial position but with the yoyo it keeps on repeating (i supose that i should not use the yoyo method...). I attach you the code I have so far:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var myTween = new Tween(rectangle, "x", Strong.easeInOut, 100,300, 1, true);

myTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);
function onFinish(e:TweenEvent):void {
myTween.yoyo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set a timeout in the onFinish method. The code should look like this:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var myTween = new Tween(rectangle, "x", Strong.easeInOut, 100,300, 1, true);

myTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);
function onFinish(e:TweenEvent):void {
  var delay:int = 1000;
  setTimeout(delay,reverse_tween); // delay - delay in milliseconds
}
function reverse_tween():void{
  myTween.yoyo();
  myTween.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: ouch....it does not work when I tried. I modifyed it in several ways but i don't know what's wrong that does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: First, can you see the error you get? and if yes, add it here. Second, the most likely reason for failing would be: the fact the myTween is not a global variable so the reverse_tween function does not access it